# What all has to happen in post-2023 election Thailand before it can have a new prime minister?

Tags: democracy, parliament, prime-minister, dictatorship, thailand

After some surprisingly strong support for "change" seen

> ...on 14 May 2023 to elect 500 members of the House of Representatives...

Wikipedia's [2023 Thai general election; Government formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_Thai_general_election#Government_formation) mentions some substantial coalition-forming activities later in May. There's nothing listed for June.

If I understand correctly, Thailand's current prime minister is General [Prayut Chan-o-cha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prayut_Chan-o-cha)

> ...a Thai politician and retired army officer who has served as the Prime Minister of Thailand since he seized power in a military coup in 2014. He is concurrently the Minister of Defence, a position he has held in his own government since 2019.

The first Wikipedia link adds:

> The Royal Thai Armed Forces pledged to respect the results of the general election and not launch a coup.

With the premise of my question being that parliament will choose a new prime minister and that it will not likely be General Prayut<sup>1</sup>, I'd like to ask:

**Question:** What all has to happen in post 2023 general election Thailand before it can have a new prime minister?

"What all..." means an answer should be more than "they have to form a government and choose one". Thailand's multiparty politics and "oscillations" with the military means that this is not such an easy question to answer.

---

<sup>1</sup>still holding my breath as of 2023-07-14

Comment: The [tag:dictatorship] tag was added as Thailand's government is currently... inadequately described as a democracy. Companion question: [Will Prayut still be Thailand's Minister of Defence if/when a new government is formed (2023) and (presumably a new) prime minister selected?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/80048/16047)

Comment: in meta [Why no love for Thailand('s politics)?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6588/16047)